# Delayed or undeliverd OTP Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently facing a significant issue with Firebase Phone Authentication in my app. Initially, when the user base was relatively small, the authentication process seemed to work seamlessly. However, as the app's downloads exceeded 5k+, I've encountered a multitude of negative feedback indicating that users are unable to receive OTPs. Even after upgrading to the Blaze plan, the problem persists.

Here's the code I've been using for phone authentication:

`PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(VerificationId, OTP); signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);`

Additionally, I've implemented the PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callback:

```
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks firebaseCallBacks =
    new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "OTP sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            VerificationId = verificationId;
            ResendToken = token;
        }
    };
```

The OnCodeSent method does work and displays the toast "OTP sent!" but the user dont get any otp.

I'd greatly appreciate any guidance on resolving this problem. Has anyone else encountered similar challenges with Firebase Phone Authentication? Are there any strategies to ensure reliable OTP delivery for a larger user base? I've exhausted the standard solutions such as upgrading the Firebase plan and ensuring network connectivity.

Thank you in advance for your insights and assistance. Your expertise will help me improve the user experience and mitigate this persistent issue.

i am disscussing this issue with Firebase Support but still didnt get to a solution.